# White page on loading php script

Tags: php, apache

I wrote a script that gets data from python and then php processes the data.
I am using loops. I have two files.

1. 2.7 mb
2. 3.1 mb

The first file is processed without problems. The second file displays a white page. When I got a white page, i can see that data continues to uploading in the SQL. That is, the process is working.

If you enable the display of errors, then the page will load.

```
[Wed Nov 17 20:44:57.403842 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 3461] [client 94.102.122.77:39008] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: profile in /var/www/.com/ip/uploadpay2.php on line 252, referer: https://.com/uploadpay2.php
```

I set in start of foreach, that

```
$profile = "";
```

And after that, the page stopped loading again, without errors, shows a white page.

in php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 1600 ;
max_input_time = 1600 ; 
max_input_nesting_level = 64 ; 
memory_limit = 512M ; 
upload_max_filesize = 200M ;
```

Comment: create a script .sh/.bat, having a web-server is not obligatory for console task

Comment: I dont understand what's being asked here. Are you asking why the script is continuing to execute showing only a white page, or why your script is showing a white page?

Comment: The script parses the data and adds it to the database. And displays the result to me. The first file outputs the result. The second file shows a white page

Comment: White page with php in Apache is usually due to some error with the code.  Error logs say anything else?  But your `LogLevel1 to debug to see more.